# Add xml declaration to ubl_bis3.xml in odoo 15

Tags: xml, odoo

We use electronic invoices from Odoo 15 in the ubl_bis3 format. When sending the invoices to the peppol Id, these xml files are rejected since they lack the XML declaration
in the first line. When we edit the files and add these declaration manually, everything works fine and the xml-files are accepted by the system.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Invoice
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    ...
```

Is there a way to add these declaration to the template file that Odoo uses to create the  xml output?
We tried to add the following lines to the template in /addons/account_edi_ubl_bis3/data/bis3_templates.xml.

```
...
<template id="export_bis3_invoice">
        <t t-set="xml_line" t-value="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"/>
        <t t-out="xml_line"/>
            <Invoice
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
                ...
```

We get then the following error:

```
File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account_edi_ubl_bis3/data/bis3_templates.xml", line 109
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values, line 109, column 38
```

How would it be possible to customize the template file in Odoo, so that it produces an ubl_bis3.xml with the missing xml-declaration in the first line?

Comment: Are you sure you have the "current" 15.0 version of odoo? Because they missed that part when introducing the ubl export feature and added it 4 months later ([see here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blame/a43a5d308b542a6e0d2a4a16e95a8186d69ffeda/addons/account_edi_ubl/models/account_edi_format.py#L209))

Comment: Under preferences it says: Odoo 15.0 (Community Edition). I have the account_edi_ubl_bis3 module installed (version 15.0.1.0).

Comment: 15.0 can mean anything from the earliest to the latest version.

Comment: OK, I checked this and in line 209 account_edi_format.py I have this code:          `# Create file content.
        xml_content = markupsafe.Markup("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>")`. But the generated xml-files doesn't have the xml-declaration.

Comment: Oh and the line adding the xml declaration was there already in earlier version without using `Markup`. It's weird that it isn't working on your side. Do you have custom modules installed?

Comment: Yes I have, but none of my modules touches the xml export (at least what I can see). From the account_edi_ubl I have installed account_edi, account_edi_facturx, account_edi_proxy_client, account_edi_ubl_bis3, account_edi_ubl_cii. Maybe I need to uninstall one of these?

Comment: Could be, but i don't think that should be a problem.